# MySQL - Match existing partial text against full text

Tags: mysql, sql, text, full-text-search, mariadb

I have a text column containing partial snippets of a longer text that I would like to update.

For example, a column might contain:

> This is a long text string that cont...

I need to replace the above with with:

> This is a long text string that contains a lot more information and should be stored in the database.

I've tried the following:

`SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE MATCH (column) AGAINST ('This is a long text string that contains a lot more information and should be stored in the database.' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);`

However, that returns many results which contain one or more of the words in the longer version of the text. How would I find existing rows which contain only the exact existing words against the longer text? The ellipses on the original snippet are intentional, as the longer string was previously truncated. I can also reasonably expect the truncated text columns to be unique, resulting in exactly one result.

**EDIT**

I've solved this by simply taking the first X characters of the longer text and matching it against the existing data. This works because of the uniqueness of each row.

Comment: The other way is like %text%... or maybe read the score generated by the match function and then order them by that and take the first row who has to be the closest one o the one who match more your words.

Comment: Tried that, but the score was much lower than other rows :(

Comment: Do only the values you want to find contain ellipses '...'?  If so, you could: column like '%...%'

Comment: No, not all columns will contain an ellipses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up I could find the matches by using `%text` instead of `%text%` and specifying only to match the first 20 characters.